# Android 7.1 Google APIs ARM - no cpu abi image available for this target

Tags: android, xamarin, android-sdk-tools, android-7.1-nougat

I am new to Xamarin and Android development. I have installed VS 2017. I have installed Google APIs ARM under Android 7.1 API 25. But I am not able to create the emulator. It says "no cpu abi image available for this target". What I might be missing in it?

[image: Android SDK]

Comment: I suggest you use one of the x86 images instead. The ARM emulators are super slow. Also make sure the AVD manager is the one installed at the Android SDK location and not somewhere else.

Comment: Restart your Visual Studio, if it not work, please install  `Intel x86 Atom_64 System`, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

After googling further i came across a helpful link

The screenshots you have included appear to show the GUI interface for the Google AVD Manager included with Android SDK Tools <= 25.x. Google made the decision to remove the GUI interface for many of their tools in Android SDK Tools 26.

We have been working on creating our own GUI interfaces to replace the ones removed by Google in their SDK Tools. You'll notice that we have our own interface for the Android SDK Manager built right into Visual Studio for Mac. We are working on a similar solution for the AVD Manager.

Until we have published our own solution I would strongly recommend the following:

Update the Android SDK Tools to >= 26.X.
Remove any AVDs that you have already created with the old tooling (they will not work).
Create new AVDs using the avdmanager CLI tools included with v. 26 of the Android SDK Tools

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/124590/no-cpuabi-system-images-available-for-this-target.html